# String Match with prefixes

Tags: algorithm, match

I have list of string which are prefix list(assuming its huge in numbers), if I want to check for given name/string which longest prefix from prefix list will be match for this name/string.
i.e. Prefix List:['good','goo','go']
Input: name:'goodboy' result: good

For small number of data in list, we can use normal Search/match techniques but for huge data, can someone please suggest how can i imporve.

Comment: You can sort the list of prefixes, and use binary search. Or you could use a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: How about putting all the prefix list in hash set and then go one letter at a time for the given string and search it in the set (like "g" , "go", "goo", "good", "goodb" , etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trie.

Here is an implementation:

````py
class Trie(dict):
    def add(self, s):
        node = self
        for ch in s:
            if ch not in node:
                node[ch] = Trie() 
            node = node[ch]
        node["end"] = True

    def findprefix(self, s):
        node = self
        len = 0
        for i, ch in enumerate(s):
            if "end" in node:
                len = i
            if ch not in node:
                break 
            node = node[ch]
        return s[:len]


trie = Trie()
for s in ["good", "goo", "go", "goodbyeparty"]:
    trie.add(s)
print(trie.findprefix("goodbye"))  # "good"```
````